# Graphics in top left of titlepage

Tags: titles

I'm working on a report and want to put a logo at the top left of the title page.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,oneside,titlepage]{book}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \title{Detailed analysis of Daffy Duck's plumage}
    \author{Elmer Fudd}
    \date{\today}

    \begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=1cm] at (current page.north west)
          {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{logo.jpg}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

However when I create the PDF, the logo is on the next page, and if I switch the positions of \maketitle and tikzpicture, the logo is on the first page and the title on the next.

I could use the titlepic-package, but here the logo is centered, and below the title and date.

Comment: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280)

Comment: You can also use tikzpagenodes or everypage to place things outside the margins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `maketitle` command creates a title page with a specific layout, I don't think you can combine it with other elements. I don't know how exactly the `titlepic` package works, but I suppose that it redefines the `maketitle` command. If you don't like how it works, you can always redefine the `maketitle` command yourself to produce any wanted layout for the title page.

If you don't want to redefine the `maketitle` command, you don't have to necessarily use it to create a title page. To create a title page, just use

```
\begin{titlepage}
    ...
\end{titlepage}
```

In that way, you are free to define any layout you want.

---

Here is the minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,titlepage]{book}

\title{Detailed analysis of Daffy Duck's plumage}
\author{Elmer Fudd}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\begin{titlepage}
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \lhead{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{profiles.png}}
    \cfoot{} % this is to remove the page number
    \hbox{}\vfill
    \begin{center}
        {\LARGE\@title}\\[3em]
        {\large\@author}\\[1.75em]
        {\large\@date}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{3cm}\vfill
\end{titlepage}

\makeatother

%\maketitle % you don't need this anymore

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, but I had to put in \setlength{\headheight}{40pt} to remove error message.

Comment: @staenne: That's a warning, no error message and the amount of the headheight length depends on the size of the logo image. Most likely the `profile.png` worked pretty well for Marko, but the scaling etc. is too large for your image. If this answer worked for you, consider to accept it please!